# "that-clause" as relative clause vs as pronoun clause

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses

I am confused by the difference between:

> It is contention about the consequence of an economic arrangement that
> is incompatible with the needs of any place.

and

> It is contention about the consequence of an economic arrangement that
> it is incompatible with the needs of any place.

Is it correct to say: about the first sentence, that- is a relative clause to add more information to a type of economic arrangement;
as to the second, that- is a pronoun clause to specify the real subject, thereby supplementing the dummy subject "it" in the beginning?

Comment: The first sentence is grammatical,. The second sentence doesn't fit together: it has an extra "it" after "that".

Comment: The second "that" is not a pronoun but a subordinator in both cases. The relative clause in the first is "that is incompatible with the needs of any place", which modifies "economic arrangement". The second sentence is an extraposition construction, where the "that" clause" is a declarative content clause functioning as extraposed subject. The subject “it” is a dummy element serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position; the extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of it but serves simply as a semantic argument of the VP.